# If the limit exists (prove) and find the value

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $$f(x, y) = \frac{x^2(x - 1) - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}, (x, y) \ne (0, 0)$$ Determine if $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ exists, and if so, find the value.

Let $y = mx$, then

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2(x - 1) - m^2x^2}{x^2 + m^2x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - 1 - m^2}{m^2 + 1} = -1 $$

Then we apply the squeeze theorem to prove $|f(x,y) - (-1)| < B(x)$ where $B(x) \to 0$

**Main question:** if we let $y = mx$, then as $y \to 0$, how can **we be sure that** $x \to 0$?

Since $x = y/m$ we see that **if** $m \ne 0$ then $x \to 0$ as $y \to 0$.

**So,** in the hypothesis when we say let $y = mx$, is it for non zero $m$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these types of questions, but why are you allowed to let $y=mx$? Unless $m$ is a variable too, I don't see how you are able to assume there is a linear relationship between them.

Comment: The first step is just to choose a *particular* curve according to which $(x,y)\to 0$, in order to find what the limit would **have** to be, *if* it exists (why? Because if the limit exists, it by definition has to be the same no matter what curve you choose). So you could have chosen $m=1$, or even $m=0$ (i.e., $y=0$. This is actually simpler). The *second* step is then, having identified the only possible limit, to check that $f$ indeed converges to that limit -- and in that second step, you don't get to make any assumption on $y$ w.r.t. $x$, besides the fact that $(x,y)\to 0$..

Comment: Why do you want to follow a curve? The definition of a limit doesn't require a curve.

Answer (score 0):

Use polar coordinates: $x = r\cos\theta, \, y = r\sin\theta$ and let $r \to 0$.

**EDIT**
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2(x - 1) - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} 
& = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^2 \cos^2\theta \, (r \cos\theta - 1) - r^2\sin^2\theta}{r^2} \\
& = \lim_{r \to 0} \left(\cos^2\theta \, (r \cos\theta - 1) - \sin^2\theta\right) \\
& = \cos^2\theta \cdot (-1) - \sin^2\theta \\
& = -1
\end{align}$$

Comment: That might help calculating the limit - if it exists, and for determining that polar coordinates are no better than regular.

Comment: It's often easier in polar coordinates. I've edited my post to show the calculation.

Comment: Using polar coordinates and letting $r\to $ is just one way for $(x.y)$ to approach $(0,0)$, you also have to consider what happens when approaching long something that isn't a straight line.

Comment: You're wrong. Notice that I don't make any assumptions about how the point approaches origo. All the possible ways (even non-paths) are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

When $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ one has
$$f(x,y)={x^3\over x^2+y^2}-1=r\cos^3\phi-1\ .$$
This immediately implies $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{r\to0+}\tilde f(r,\phi)=-1\ .$$